# Xamarin Forms - Validate Entry Textbox If Empty

Tags: c#, ios, validation, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to validate whether a textbox is empty before proceeding.

It's working only if you click the button without entering in any details when the page loads.

But if you enter in details, then delete it and then click the button, it doesn't validate and continues to the next page with an empty data.

Here's my code:

XAML

```
<Entry x:Name="BillingFirstName" Placeholder="First name *" PlaceholderColor="Gray" />
```

CS

```
async void ProceedPaymentBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (BillingFirstName.Text == null)
  {
   await DisplayAlert("Billing", "Please enter a first name.", "OK");
   return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an "empty" `TextBox` can be `null` OR contains 0 characters OR contain just whitespace.  `String` contains helper methods to check for these conditions

```
if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(BillingFirstName.Text) || 
    (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(BillingFirstName.Text))
```